# How do I get auto-suggestions for array options when typing in Vim?

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, intellisense

[image]

Let's say I type

```
a = [1, 2]
```

in a .py file in vim and when I type "a." and hit TAB, I would like to get suggestion menu that is related to lists.

Edit 1 in response to Robin's comment:
I think it's possible in vim, because there is a plugin that checks if a given python code is a valid code (I don't know what the plugin is called). Take a look:

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Recent versions of vim come with an omnicompletion script called pythoncomplete.

Open up a python file, and type

```
:set completefunc?
```

to check what the current completion function is. If you get back

```
completefunc=
```

then no completionfunction is currently set. You can set pythoncomplete to be the completion function by typing

```
:set completefunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

and you can set this to be the default for python files using (in your vimrc)

```
autocmd FileType python set completefunc=pythoncomplete#Complete
```

Now when you're in vim, you can use omnicomplete using <kbd>Ctrl+X</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl+O</kbd> and you should get a popup menu as shown below:

[image: list completion]

You can also bind this to the tab key in insert mode with (in your vimrc):

```
inoremap <Tab> <C-x><C-o>
```

To find out more about interacting with the dropdown menu that appears, try

```
:help ins-completion
```

Comment: I think that's the answer. I have another question, though: "How do I automatically get rid of the extra documentation window that opens up at the top ([Scratch] [Preview])?".

Comment: Check :set completeopt?. The option 'preview' in there makes the preview window appear with the docstring in it. If you set completeopt without preview it should no longer appear.

Comment: @Spiritwalker also see http://info.birnamdesigns.com/wiki/Vim_close_preview_window_after_omnifunc_selectionfor a tip on how to auto-close the preview window when you leave insert mode or move your cursor (I prefer the insert mode method)

Comment: @Michael, thanks for the link. I think you have to remove 'for' at the end of your link.

Comment: Oh you're right. I wonder how I did that.  Here's the correct link: http://info.birnamdesigns.com/wiki/Vim_close_preview_window_after_omnifunc_selection

Comment: It works great! Maybe I am asking for too much but is there a way of having the contents of the preview window show up in the menu itself? The reason is sometimes the menu covers the preview window, sometimes preview window's size gets bigger when there is a lot of text, and doesn't get smaller when there is less text.

Answer (score 3):

Read one of the many blog posts on setting up Vim as a Python IDE. [Here's one](http://blog.dispatched.ch/2009/05/24/vim-as-python-ide/) to get you started.  In particular, you are interested in the OmniComplete function.

This is bound by default to the keystroke <kbd>Ctrl-x</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> but you can rebind it to the tab key.

Note that it is not sensitive to the type of a variable.  It can complete for you if you type:

```
string.<ctl-x><ctl-o>
```

you'll get a list of the string object methods.  But if you do as you described in your question something like:

```
x = "a string"

x.<ctl-x><ctl-o>
```

vim will not know that the variable `x` holds a string, and will not be able to  supply a list of methods.

For information on omnicomplete:

```
:help omnifunc
```

Comment: @Spiritwalker If it is possible, I do not know how to do it.  I would welcome really another answer that could prove me wrong, because that would be quite useful.

Comment: See also http://www.mohdshakir.net/2007/12/27/enable-vim-code-python-auto-complete

Comment: The only way to find out what you can do with an object is evaluating everything --- which means it is more suited for an interactive interpreter interface such as IDLE, where it is already know what `a` refers to.